# next activity is not starting on button click from a fragment activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am calling an `Activity` on a button click but its not opening I have set `onClickListener` on button and calling from `Intent` also set it in android manifest but still its not working. Please look into this
HERE is my **PDFRenderFragment** class

**Edited Code**
    **PDFRenderFragment.java**
    package com.blogspot.hongthaiit.pdfrender;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFRenderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
    private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
    private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
    private ImageView image;
    private Button btnPrevious;
    private Button btnNext;
    private Button searchPaper;
    private EditText paperName;

    public PDFRenderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfrender, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Retain view references.
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        btnPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
        btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        searchPaper = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.searchPaper);
        paperName =(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.paperName);

        //set buttons event
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked
        searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowWebView.class);
                intent.putExtra("PAPERNAME", paperName.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        int index = 0;
        // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
        }
        showPage(index);



    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            openRenderer(activity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
            Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            closeRenderer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (null != currentPage) {
            outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDF renderer
     * @param activity
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
        // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
        fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("resume.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
    }

    /**
     * Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
     */
    private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        pdfRenderer.close();
        fileDescriptor.close();
    }

    /**
     * Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
     * @param index The page index.
     */
    private void showPage(int index) {
        if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }
        // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        //open a specific page in PDF file
        currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
        // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
        currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        // showing bitmap to an imageview
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUIData();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
     */
    private void updateUIData() {
        int index = currentPage.getIndex();
        int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
        btnNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
        //getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name, index + 1, pageCount));
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
                } else {
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
                }
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Here is the **Manifest** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blogspot.hongthaiit.pdfrender">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShowWebView"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the **second class**, which I want to open when the button is clicked

```
package com.blogspot.hongthaiit.pdfrender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShowWebView extends Activity {
    WebView browser;
    Button searchPaper;
    EditText paperName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_web_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String PAPERNAME = intent.getStringExtra("PAPERNAME");
        //search for paper
        /*searchPaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchPaper);
        paperName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.paperName);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = PAPERNAME;

                browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                browser.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });*/
        browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browser.loadUrl(PAPERNAME);
    }
    /*private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }*/


}
```

plz help me fixing this.

Comment: Use `getActivity().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: How are you determining that onClick method being called? Have you put a log print here? A break point?

Comment: no i havent put log i setOnClicklistener on searchpaper button and use intent to open next activity

Comment: thats the problem logcat doesnt show any error

Comment: Why do you call setOnClickListener for searchPaper button twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the onclickListener twice for searchPaper button and the second one is empty

Comment: correct... :) ..the second onClickListener overrides the first, so it can´t work...

Comment: oh i see sorry let me fix that and check it again

Comment: @Mohit , it´s definetely a mistake, no matter if it fixes your problem. So you should change it at all...

Comment: no errors is showing in logcat.. what should i do now?

Comment: Can you please update your code in the question and include your manifest as well ....

Comment: I was able to fix the problem, there was a silly mistake made by me.

Answer (score 1):

what error you're getting? paste your logcat.  your code

```
searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowWebView.class);
                    intent.putExtra("PAPERNAME", paperName.toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

is enough to open the new activity.   Why have you used this peace of code 
....

```
searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

                            }
                          }
                       );
```

Seems this one creating a problem. check this or paste your logcat.

Comment: i want to open the next activity on a button click i have done it many time but never faced problem like this

Comment: comment this piece of code and check... //set OnclickListner on button searchpaper
        searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {

                                           }
                                       }
        );

Comment: I know, that's how everyone open the activity from the fragment.. just check once what I said. look at above comment.

Comment: It's not working because you have used searchpaper.setOnClickListener() method twice.

Comment: oh yeah i got it thnx

Comment: @techniqez: you should format your answer, by that way it´s difficult to read. Put your code into format and leave your other comments out of your code example.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : sure will take care of formatting next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting flag 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

On your intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set OnclickListner on button searchpaper
        searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {

                                           }
                                       }
        );
```

Please check above code. In OnClickListener() there is no code. So, It will override previous ClickListener operation in which you wrote code to redirect an activity. Please remove this above code.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfrender, container, false);

    //Write your code here，such as OnClickListener
    Button searchPaper = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.searchPaper);
    searchPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(v);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void click(View v) {
    EditText paperName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.paperName);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowWebView.class);
    intent.putExtra("PAPERNAME", paperName.toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```